# All pairs of X,Y coordinates from Each Point to Every other Point with Java

Tags: java

Greetings,

I am trying to find all pairs of X,Y axis Points in Java from each point to every other point as seen below. I am using Eclipse on Windows. Much appreciate for the help on this problem.

Three point example: (1.0, 2.0) (2.0, 2.0) (3.0, 4.0)

All pairs from each to every other point:

Output:

(1.0 ,2.0) (2.0, 2.0)
(1.0, 2.0) (3.0, 4.0)

(2.0, 2.0) (1.0, 2.0)
(2.0, 2.0) (3.0, 4.0)

(3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 2.0)
(3.0, 4.0) (2.0, 2.0)

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: What have you done already? This smells like homework.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do other people's homework on Sundays. Maybe Tuesday if we're not busy?

Comment: This is a small part of a project that involves segment intersection and dijkstras algorithm.  I am currently computing the combinations manually and loading them into a source text file.  If anyone knows the logic/code to do this, Id appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the list two times and exclude the ones that are same:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new Point(1, 2));
points.add(new Point(2, 2));
points.add(new Point(3, 4));
printCombinations(points);

public static void printCombinations(List<Point> points) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j)
                System.out.println(points.get(i) + ":" + points.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Morja.  I'm not sure why this was closed but your implementation is "on point."

Comment: Also, for those who like excel, another nice solution was posted here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=412952

Answer (score 0):

Short hint: go through all points, iterate through all following points and add the pair somewhere.